# ARToolKit tilt not supported

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, artoolkit, iphone-ar-toolkit

I have two augmented reality tool kits, [ARTollkit1](https://github.com/nielswh/iPhone-AR-Toolkit) and [ARTollkit2](https://github.com/zac/iphonearkit/), first one is more accurate than second one but with one missing functionality than when I tilt the device the tags do not go up or down. For reference see this [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xtCC3mjxnuk).